# I have two width declarations. Which one will get applied?

Tags: html, css, viewport

Let's say we have a HTML page which has the structure as

```
<html>
<body>
    <table id="myTable">
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have a CSS defined as;

```css
#myTable {width:100%;width:900px;}
```

Now my question is this table is indirectly also affected by the viewport (or available browser space)
So what out of the 2 values (px or %) would win ? That is how much space would the table actually take in the layout ? If current browser space is, say 1000px, would it take that value (which means 100% overriding 900 px value)
At a broader level, can we generalize this working that % or px value always wins ?
Would this depend on the DOCTYPE that is set ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what out of the 2 values (px or %) would win ?

The pixel width would win, but not because it is defined with a pixel unit.

Since the two rules appear in the same ruleset, their selectors have equal specificity (because they are identical), so the last one wins.

The choice of units is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok..So in the CSS, if the px value would have come first and then the %, in that case would the % value have won ?

Comment: Yes … or just remove the pixel value. `{foo: bar; foo: baz}` means the same as `{foo: baz}` except the latter is less confusing and needs less bandwidth. The only time you should use the same property name twice in one ruleset is when you are dealing with values that aren't always supported (such as when using [rgba colours with an rgb fallback](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/#fallback-color))

Comment: This also means, that if you would have `#myTable {width: 100%;} #myTable {width: 900px;}` then px will win, because pixels are last. However, this doesn't mean, that full #myTable, gets overwritten.. just the width part.

Answer (score 0):

px will win it will go with 900px instead of 100% of width i dont know the reason but i have test it

Comment: it will go with the last style define ... if you put 900px before 100% than it will show 100% not 900px

Answer (score 0):

px will win the reason behind that is the last value is in px. Whenever a css file is detected it is checked from top to bottom and whatever it found in the last is applied. for example

we have

```
#home {width:100%;color:#fffccc;}
```

Then again at the bottom we define

```
#home {width:100%;color:red;}
```

The element with id home will have red as color for their font.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, always the last defined style wins unless the before one has !important.

For example

```
.myClass{
    width: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

In this case the width would be 400px as it the rule that appears last when the CSS is parsed.

```
.myClass{
    width: 200px !important;
    width: 400px;
}
```

In this case the width would be 200px as it the rule is made **important**